# Find element on the page where text is null

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver

I would like to be able to find element on the page where the text element is empty:

```
<h4 class="dest-sitemap__sublist-title dest-sitemap__sublist-title-empty"></h4>
```

There is one element like this one the page but dont know how translate text null to selenium -.-

When used :

```
elems = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('h4')
for elem in elems:
    print(elem.text)
```

Return was:

```
element 1
element 2

element 4
element 5
```

Comment: Null and empty string are different things

Comment: Sorry messed up when adding question ( I am in hurry and must leave house) 

Here is the element I cannot map:
<h4 class="sitemap__title sitemap__title-empty"></h4>

I will try edit one I am back

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is the class `dest-sitemap__sublist-title-empty` unique for this element? you can use it

```
elem = driver.find_element_by_class_name('dest-sitemap__sublist-title-empty')
```

Comment: Well... It is working :D but with xpath I was pointing precise element with:
"//following::div[1]//li[{ItemNumber}]//a[@class='AnotherClass']")

I am looking right now how I can achieve it with find_element_by_class. 

If you have any handy solution I would love to see it, but marking as solved anyway as provided solution works nice ! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use XPATH and text() function.
XPATH provides a rich possibility to locate elements.
So if you want to locate all h4 elements with empty strings, you can use the following way.

```
xpath = "//h4[text()='']"
elems = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(xpath)
```

Comment: I try to use it however I am unable to locate the element with this solution. I try both  '' and ' '.